# Trying to use raycasting for touch screen interactions (A mistake)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, raycasting

So, I'm not used to raycasting, this is the first time I've ever used it. Basically I'm trying to use it to mimic a mouse click, because this program is meant for touch screens, and UI elements are not an option. The code is attached to a 3d game object in the world, and when I tap on the touch screen where I see it, I need it to trigger and load a different scene. However, the code seems to always be firing, even overriding UI elements no matter where I tap. Most people seem to have issues with raycasts not hitting, but I've got the opposite problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
void Update(){
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (touch.position);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject)
                SceneManager.LoadScene (buttonIdentifier);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Your question does not even describe your problem. Are you trying to detect click on sprite? on canvas image? on a 3D mesh? what is currently happening that you don't like?

Comment: I edited it and hopefully clarified it.

Comment: And I provided an answer. Did it work?

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly, or seems to, anyway. Sorry about the delay, I wasn't able to check it until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even overriding UI elements no matter where I tap.

This problem and the rest of your problems can be solved by **not** using raycast at-all. Simply implement `IPointerClickHandler` and overide the `OnPointerClick` function. After that, attach `PhysicsRaycaster` to the Camera.

The code below will do all of these for you including attaching `PhysicsRaycaster`. Just attach the script to the 3D Object you want to detect the click on and that's it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Clicker : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{

    void Start()
    {
        Camera.main.gameObject.AddComponent<PhysicsRaycaster>();
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

        Debug.Log("Clicked!");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(buttonIdentifier);
    }
}
```